# Delete from the database using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to make one delete function, but I do not know what steps did wrong?

This is the file model:

```
function delete()
{
    $this->db->delete('ns_categories', array('cat_id' => $cat_id));     
}
```

Controller:

```
function delete()
{
    $this->cat_model->delete();
    $cat_id=$this->uri->segment(3);
    if($cat_id->delete()) return json_encode(array("success" => true));            
}
```

View:

```
<td class="centeralign"><a class="deleterow" href="<?php echo anchor('admin/categories/delete' .<?php echo $row['cat_id']; ?>"><span class="icon-trash"></span></a></td>
```

Please help me.

Comment: rename your function delete to something like deleteCat or something. I beleive delete is a keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't done anything right, no offense. It's a mess.

View:

You missed a forward slash here:

```
href="<?php echo 'admin/categories/delete' .<?php echo $row['cat_id']; ?>"
                                        ^^^
```

...but you don't use `anchor()` this way anyways, it generates an entire link. And you have nested two `<?php echo`s... What a mess. Do it like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/categories/delete/'.$row['cat_id']; ?>">
```

Model:

You haven't defined `$cat_id` in the model's `delete` function. Also, don't return json from a model. Do it like this:

```
function delete($cat_id = null)
{
    return $this->db->delete('ns_categories', array('cat_id' => $cat_id));
}
```

Controller:

You're calling `delete` as a method of `$cat_id` which makes no sense, as the variable contains a number - not an object you can call a method on. You also have to echo/print the json, and you should set json headers. Do it like this:

```
function delete($cat_id = null) {
    $status = $this->cat_model->delete($cat_id);
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array("success" => $status));
}
```

You should use POST method to delete things, otherwise people can delete things accidentally or do stupid tricks like `<img src="delete/item/1">`

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra **echo** from link:

```
<td class="centeralign">
    <a class="deleterow" href="<?php echo anchor('admin/categories/delete' . $row['cat_id']); ?>">
        <span class="icon-trash"></span>
    </a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller delete function you have got the category id after calling the delete function of model why? And in your model function from where you are getting `$cat_id` ?? it should be like this

```
function Category_delete(){
$cat_id=$this->uri->segment(3);   
if($this->cat_model->delete($cat_id)) return json_encode(array("success" => true));            
}
```

In your view you have opened the `<?php` again and also you are using `anchor` function in the `href` `anchor` function generates the complete `<a>` tag see reference for helpers [CI Helpers](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html)

```
<td class="centeralign"><a class="deleterow" href="<?php echo site_url('admin/categories/Category_delete/'.$row['cat_id']; ?>">
<span class="icon-trash"></span></a></td>
```

And you should rename the functions because delete may be a keyword so use ordinary names for the functions